# How to combine group-starting-with and group-by in XSLT 2.0?

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to combine group-starting-with and group-by in XSLT 2.0

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="xxx[@attr='yyy']" group-by="@id" group-starting-with="xxx[@attr='yyy']">
...
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

How to achieve such combination?

input:

```
<root> 
        <library id="L1">
            <genre id="a">
                <shelf1 id="1">                
                    <book id="a1" action="borrow">
                        <attributes>
                            <user>John</user>                    
                        </attributes>
                        <other1>y</other1>
                    </book>  
                    <book id="a1" action="extend">
                        <attributes>
                            <user>Woo</user>           
                            <length>3</length>
                        </attributes>
                        <other2>y</other2>
                    </book> 
    </shelf1>
</genre>
    </library>
    </root>
```

Output:

```
<root> 
    <library id="L1">
        <genre id="a">
            <shelf1 id="1">                
                <book id="a1" action="borrow">
                    <attributes>
                        <user>Woo</user>           
                        <length>3</length>                   
                    </attributes>
                    <other1>y</other1>
                </book> 
</shelf1>
</genre>
</library>
</root>
```

My XSL snippet:

```
<xsl:template match="genre/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />

            <xsl:apply-templates select="
     book[@action='extend']                             
         [not( preceding-sibling::book[@action='borrow'])]" />


              <xsl:for-each-group
                select="book[@action='borrow'] 
             |   
            book[@action='extend']
                [preceding-sibling::book[@action='borrow']]"
                group-by="@id" group-starting-with="book[@action='borrow']"> (: "This is the one which needs to be combined :)
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()[1]">
                        <xsl:copy>   
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
                            <xsl:call-template name="merge-books-deeply">    
                                <xsl:with-param name="books" select="current-group()" />
                                <xsl:with-param name="name-path" select="()" />
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:copy>
                    </xsl:for-each>     
                </xsl:for-each-group>


            <xsl:apply-templates select="                             
     node()[ not( self::book[@action=('borrow','extend')])]" />

        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

For every node that has the same `@id` with `action=borrow` followed by *one or more* node with `action=extend`

- Merge it together to the node with action=borrow.
- Merge the attributes children together such that it will have all the unique attributes from the siblings with the latest value.
- leave other children unchanged

Thanks.
John

Answer (score 2):

Well the construct provided in the language is an either group-by or group-starting-with so it is not clear to us what you expect when you ask to combine them.

What you can do is nest `for-each-group` e.g.

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="xxx[@att = 'yyy']" group-by="@id">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-starting-with="xxx[@attr = 'yyy']">...</xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

although while writing that I wonder what sense it makes to have a grouping population `xxx[@att = 'yyy']` and a group starting with pattern `xxx[@att = 'yyy']`.

So I think you need to explain in more detail how your input looks and how you want to group it.

Comment: I have added the xsl snippet with the input and expacted output. Would you mind having a look? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should do:

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="library | genre"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="shelf1"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="library | genre">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="library | genre | shelf1"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="shelf1">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>

        <xsl:for-each-group select="current()/book" group-by="@id">
            <book id="{current-grouping-key()}" action="borrow">
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[@action='extend']/*"/>
            </book>
        </xsl:for-each-group>

    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```